# NsMutable Array not adding object iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am accessing contact from user phone. Everything is working perfectly but when I add it into the `NSMutableArray` then nothing is entered. In breakpoint when I click on array its showing 0X16bed870. My code is as follow.

```
-(void)mycontact
{
    NSMutableArray * contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];

    if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"This app previously was refused permissions to contacts; Please go to settings and grant permission to this app so it can use contacts" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        return;
    }

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (granted == YES) {

            //keys with fetching properties

            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];

            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;

            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];

            NSError *error;

            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];

            if (error) {

                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);

            } else {

                NSString *phone;
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                UIImage *profileImage;

                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {

                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;

                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    } else if (firstName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    } else {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }

                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                    if (image != nil) {
                        profileImage = image;
                    }else{
                        profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                    }

                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {

                        phone = [label.value stringValue];

                        if ([phone length] > 0) {
                            [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                        }
                    }

                    NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    for(int j=0;j<[contactNumbersArray count];j++)
                    {
                        NSString *newString = [[contactNumbersArray[j] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                                [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                                               componentsJoinedByString:@""];

                        contactNumbersArray[j]=newString;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: The `NSMutableArray` wouldn't be `nil` would it (common error)?  Which array are you referring to?  Also why are you using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`?  You don't appear to be accessing the UI...

Comment: for me it is not clear the question: which array are you talking about? contactNumbersArray? where did you put the breakpoint to check its content?

Comment: @ddb
yes i am talking about contactNumbersArray. i have put break point on
  phone = [label.value stringValue];
its showing value of phone. but not adding in contactNumbersArray array

Comment: after the execution of `phone = [label.value stringValue];`, the condition `[phone length] > 0` is true/`YES`?

Comment: @ddb The same code is running in simulator. but not in real device.
is there any limit for NSMutableArray?? i mean in simulator i have only 10 contacts . and in real device may be more so is it problem?

Comment: @ddb yes it is true.it is going in if block.

Comment: are you sure that in real device each contact has at least 1 phone number set?

Comment: @ddb no some numbers have only email id. and some are from facebook.

Comment: your code will work if at least one contact has one phone numbers. So (for testing purpose) at least add one fake contact with a phone number. You will see that for that contact the phone number will be added in your array

Comment: @ddb ihave triwd that but not working. Still not adding in NSMutableArray

Comment: if it works on simulator, there is no reason why it should not work on real device. Just be sure you have a complete contact list (complete about the user details you need)

Comment: @ddb is it some memory issue?? i means if i have 500 contact than it is issue of NSMutableArray with so many numbers??

Comment: you can have an array with how many elements you want, that's not an issue

Comment: ok thanks for help. but now please if possible provide me some solution